# Is there a command in ed that repeats the last command?

Tags: ed

Is there a command in `ed` that repeats the last command? I know that one can repeat the last search (with `//`) but a command to repeat and/or edit the last command without having to retype it would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no  magic command in `ed` that repeats the last command.  If you are using `G/re/` to interactively give editing commands on lines matching `/re/`, then you may use `&` to repeat the last such entered command, and you mentioned `//` to repeat the last search, as would `??` do (but backwards).

However, you can give `ed` a readline history and command line editing facilities using the `rlwrap` tool:

```
rlwrap ed somefile
```

This allows you to

- press <kbd>Up-arrow</kbd> to recall recently entered commands etc., and to
- move around on the current line of input (using `vi` or `emacs` editing mode depending on your setting of `editing-mode` in `~/.inputrc`),
- editing the current line of input as you would the shell's command line , before issuing a command.
- It also gives you persistent history by saving it in a `~/.ed_history` file.

See also `man rlwrap` once you have installed `rlwrap` using your package manager (or from [GitHub](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap)).